# Passing values from dropDown list to Database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, json.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a form with two dropDown boxes with hard coded values. I need to pass the values selected by the user from the view to controller and store it in a database table.

This is HTML code for the dropDown.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="UserType">User Type:</label>
  <select name="usertype" class="form-control" id="drpUserType">
    <option value="0">Please Select</option>
    <option value="regular">Regular</option>
    <option value="preLoader">Pre Loader</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This is the script and the AJAX. This will pass the values to the controller.

```
$("#btnSubmitCustomer").click(function (){
  var customer = {};

  customer.ID = $("#hdnCustomerID").val();
  customer.UserType = $("#drpUserType").val();

  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: {customer : customer},
          dataType: "json",
          url: "@Url.Action("Save", "Customer")",
          success: function (response){
                if(response.type == "Success"){
                    notifyMe("Customer Added Successfully", "Success");
                    clearForm();
                    setDataTable();
                    $('#customerModal').modal('hide');
                }
            },
            error: function (error){
                console.log(error)
                $('#loading_spinner').hide();
            }
  });
});
```

This is the controller code.

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Save(Customer customer)
    {
        bool userType;
        if (customer.UserType.Equals("preLoader"))
        {
            userType = customer.UserType == true;
        }
        else
        {
            userType = customer.UserType == false;
        }

        try
        {
            Customer cst = new Customer();
            using (MyDBContext myDBContext = new MyDBContext())
            {
                if (customer != null)
                {
                    DateTime localTime = DateTime.Now;

                    if (customer.ID == 0)
                    {
                        cst.UserType = userType;

                        myDBContext.Customer.Add(cst);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int customerID = customer.ID;
                        Customer customerOld = myDBContext.Customer.Where(x => x.ID == customerID).FirstOrDefault();
                        customerOld.UserType = customer.UserType;
                    }
                    myDBContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            return Json(new { type = "Success", data = cst });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
            string message = ex.Message;
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                message += ex.InnerException.Message;
            }
            _Common.Log(message, "Customer", "save");
           return Json(new { type = "Error", message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

In MySql table the userType is tinyint(1). I need to verify the usertype via the dropDown box and assign '1' if its "preLoader | true" or '0' if its "regular | false". But am getting false whatever the user selected option is.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Is the value of Drop-down(customer.UserType) comes to the Click function? Have you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code when passing data

```
var customer ={
ID = $("#hdnCustomerID").val();
UserType = $("#drpUserType").val();
};
```

In ajax:

```
   $.ajax({
              ...
              data: JSON.stringify({ customer: customer }),
              ...
          });
```